# npm scripts not running in series

Tags: npm

I want to run eslint as a prestart script so if it fails it won't run the build script, but even when the eslint returns "clean" result it still stops the following scripts from running.
So as you can see in the example below, the testing is not running.
I've even tried to replace the order and run the test first, but then the lint script doesn't run.

Any ideas?

```
"scripts": {
"prestart": "npm run lint:watch && npm run test:watch",
"start": "open:src",
"open:src": "nodemon --watch server --exec babel-node --debug=5858 --inspect server/srcServer.js --delay 2",
"lint": "node_modules/.bin/esw webpack.config.* --cache --max-warnings 0 src server",
"lint:watch": "npm run lint -- --watch",
"test": "mocha --reporter progress server/testSetup.js 'src/**/*.test.js'",
"test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
},
```

Answer (score -1):

Now I know how it feels to be dumb :)
The "watch" in the test and lint caused it to stop since it doesn't exit.
Thank me very much for solving my issue.